# Input validation checking both for duplicates and format using array and for loop

Tags: java, validation, input, for-loop, while-loop

Hoping someone could assist. Missing something obvious I think. I have to get a user to input an account number. I need to validate this against two checks. One being that it is not yet used and that it is in the correct format. 
I have played around with this and tried different ways of doing this. I think that the reason it fails is because halfway through going through the array, I am asking for user input.

It stops the for-loop and then continues from there when user has input the data. how do I validate both?

```
System.out.println("Please enter an ID (format PNOnnn)");
String pnoID = console.next();
boolean pnoIDValid = false;
while (pnoIDValid);
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pno.length ; i++)
    {
        if (pno[i] != null)
        {
            if (pnoID.compareToIgnoreCase(pno[i].getmID()) == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("ID already used");
                //pnoID = console.next();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(pnoID.matches("PNO\\d{3}")))  
                {
                    System.out.println("Must be in format PNOnnn");
                    //pnoID = console.next();
                }
                else
                {
                    pnoIDValid = true;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if this is not resulting in the array not getting checked. I have tried it this way as well. logically it makes sense to me, but it is just not working.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a ID (format PNOnnn)");
String pnoID = console.next();
boolean pnoIDValid = false;
while (pnoIDValid);
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pno.length ; i++)
    {
        if (pno[i] != null)
        {
            if ((pnoID.compareToIgnoreCase(pno[i].getmID()) == 0) || 
                      (!(pnoID.matches ("PNO\\d{3}"))))
            {
                System.out.println("ID already used");
                pnoID = console.next();
            }
            else
            {
                pnoIDValid = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I eventually went with:

```
int subSelection = console.nextInt();
if(subSelection == 1){
    System.out.println("Enter ID"); 
    String pnoID = cons.next(); 
    int test1=0; int test2=0; 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pno.length ; i++){
        if (pno[i]!=null && pnoID.compareTo(pno[i].getmID()) == 0)){
            test1 = 1;
        }else{
            test2 = 1;
        }
    }
    int test3 = 0; int test4 = 0;
    if (pnoID.matches("PNO\\d{3}")){
        test3 = 1;
    }else{
        test4 = 1;
    }
    if (test1 == 1 && test4 == 1){
        System.out.println("This ID  exists or format invalid");
    }else{
        System.out.println("enter name (first and last)");
        String name = cons.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter phone number");
        String phone = cons.nextLine();
    }
```

The odd thing however is that the first time i go through this, I am able to enter the details correctly. The second time however it is not giving me the option to enter an ID. It shows the question "enter id", but then immediately goes to the next question "enter name". 
I have two scanners; one for menu selections and one for userinput. might this cause a conflict?

RESOLVED:

This has now been resolved as well. From what I have read online; with the scanner, a new line character (carriage return/enter key stroke) is left in the buffer and this is picked up, whihc results in the second console entry being skipped.

The suggested solution is to use bufferedreader nextLine() which I tried for all string entries and this has successfully resolved my issue.

Comment: This question was answered within the question itself, and does not need to remain open.

Answer (score 1):

Extract uniqueness check to separate method:

```
private boolean isIDUnique(String pnoID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pno.length; i++) {
        if (pno[i] != null && pnoID.compareToIgnoreCase(pnoID)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Main method:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a ID (format PNOnnn)");
String pnoID;
boolean pnoIDValid = false;
do {
    pnoID = console.next();
    if (!isIDUnique(pnoID) {
        System.out.println("ID is not unique");
    } else if (!pnoID.matches("PNO\\d{3}") {
        System.out.println("Invalid format");
    } else {
        pnoIDValid = true;
    } 
} while(!pnoIDValid);
```